# Why “ce” and not “ces”?

Tags: grammaire, démonstratifs

> **Ce** *sont* les chaussures de Pierre.

Why it is **ce**? I think it should be **ces**, because *sont* is a plural verb.

Comment: *Ce* is a pronoun and *ces* is an adjective.

Comment: you know that doesn't really clear anything up, right? According to Lawless French, they're both "demonstrative adjectives". "ce, cet, cette, and ces" all mean "this/those".